# Getting an error "This row already belongs to this table" in `GridView`

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the this error when trying to display all the users from Active Directory in my `GridView`

```
 This row already belongs to this table.
```

This is my code I am using:

```
DirectoryEntry objDirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(strADPath, strUsername, strPassword);
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, strADPath, strUsername, strPassword);
            UserPrincipal usr = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
            PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(usr);
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = ps.FindAll();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn(); ;
            col = new DataColumn("First Name");
            dt.Columns.Add(col);
            col = new DataColumn("Last Name");
            dt.Columns.Add(col);
            col = new DataColumn("Last Logon");
            dt.Columns.Add(col);
            col = new DataColumn("Last Password Reset");
            dt.Columns.Add(col);
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            foreach (UserPrincipal u in results)
            {
               
                dr["First Name"] = u.DisplayName;
                dr["Last Name"] = u.SamAccountName;
                dr["Last Logon"] = u.LastLogon.ToString();
                dr["Last Password Reset"] = u.LastPasswordSet.ToString();
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            grdViewAllADSUsers.DataSource = dt;
            grdViewAllADSUsers.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

I am not sure what that means?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();` be inside the for-each?

Comment: Hi Yes, Thanks it is working now.  Missed that one :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        foreach (UserPrincipal u in results)
        {
           
            dr["First Name"] = u.DisplayName;
            dr["Last Name"] = u.SamAccountName;
            dr["Last Logon"] = u.LastLogon.ToString();
            dr["Last Password Reset"] = u.LastPasswordSet.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

With:

```
        foreach (UserPrincipal u in results)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["First Name"] = u.DisplayName;
            dr["Last Name"] = u.SamAccountName;
            dr["Last Logon"] = u.LastLogon.ToString();
            dr["Last Password Reset"] = u.LastPasswordSet.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

You're creating a DataRow, and then repeatedly trying to add it to the table. By creating it in the for each loop, it's a new row every time you go to add the information to the table.